# Finding subgraphs K3_3 in a given undirected graph in Python

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I'm trying to solve the following problem - I have an undirected graph and trying to calculate the amount of subgraphs K3_3 (complete bipartite graph) that are inside of this graph. There are some checks that one can do with `networkx` library for example - `Graph.subgraph` class, but I'm not sure how one can use it. Are there any suggestions - either on pure python or using libraries, where one can start?

Solution that I have come to atm is the following(wrong one):

```
import itertools as it
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite

def calc_planar(G):
    res=True
    bad_m=[]
    n=len(G.nodes())
    if n>5:
        for i in it.combinations(G.nodes(),6):
            if bipartite.is_bipartite(G):
                X, Y = bipartite.sets(G)
                if len(X)==3:
                    result=False
                    bad_m=i
    return res,len(bad_m)/6
```

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: What is the expected answer?  Can you label the nodes and show each solution?

Comment: I see you added a solution, so what are you still asking?

Comment: My solution is wrong, I would like to have new ideas/approaches if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue is that you are computing the bipartite sets on the full graph each time, rather than using a subgraph induced using the nodes in `i`.

Here is my implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Compute the number of complete, bipartite subgraphs with (3, 3) nodes.
"""
import networkx as nx

from networkx.algorithms import bipartite
from itertools import combinations, product

def get_complete_bipartite_subgraphs(graph, k):
    assert len(graph) >= 2*k, "Graph must be larger than 2k!"
    output = []
    for nodes in combinations(graph.nodes, 2*k):
        subgraph = graph.subgraph(nodes)
        try:
            s1, s2 = bipartite.sets(subgraph)
            if (len(s1) == k) & (len(s2) == k) & (len(subgraph.edges) == k*k):
                output.append(subgraph)
        except:
            pass
    return output


def test():

    # complete, bipartite graphs
    edges = list(product(list(range(3)), list(range(3, 6))))
    assert len(get_complete_bipartite_subgraphs(nx.Graph(edges), 3)) == 1
    assert len(get_complete_bipartite_subgraphs(nx.Graph(edges), 2)) == 9

    # superset of a bipartite graph, but still bipartite
    edges.append((5, 6))
    assert len(get_complete_bipartite_subgraphs(nx.Graph(edges), 3)) == 1

    # superset of a bipartite graph but not bipartite itself
    edges.append((0, 1))
    assert len(get_complete_bipartite_subgraphs(nx.Graph(edges), 3)) == 0

    # bipartite but not complete
    edges = list(zip(list(range(3)), list(range(3, 6))))
    assert len(get_complete_bipartite_subgraphs(nx.Graph(edges), 3)) == 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```